# Remove FormBuilder html markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, formbuilder

How do I remove or edit the default content generated on the create view of a scaffolded item in rails ?

Right now my _form.html.erb file looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <%= form_for(@player) do |f| %>
  <% if @player.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@player.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this player from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @player.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
.
.
.
.
.
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => "btn btn-default" %>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

and visually it looks like this : [image: Visual aspect of _form]

Could someone point me in the right direction please ? I'm quite new with ruby and this is my first app.

Comment: Hi, is that my answer below solve your problem?

Comment: I'll try it in about 2 hours. I was going to sleep when I wrote the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would have file name `new.html.erb` in your `player` views module. In that, code would look like this,

```
<h1>New Player</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', players_path %>
```

From that, you could delete that New User header and back link.

Comment: Damn I'm so stupid ! It was right in front of me the whole time ! Thank you rick !!

Comment: Ohh it's fine as you are new in this and you could up vote this answer. Thank you.